# Get all hidden href link selenium python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am new in python selenium. and i want to get all the hidden href link

```
<div class="page-body">
  <div class="page-title"></div>
  <div class="page cursorPointer">
    <a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Verified"></a></div>
</div>
```

and this my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests
import re
from openpyxl import Workbook

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.get(
       "https://someurl.com")

    pagelist = []

    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'page cursorPointer'}):
        page = a.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

    pagelist.append(page.get_attribute("href"))

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Page': pagelist})
    df.to_excel('pagelist.xlsx', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

i got this error :

> page = a.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href]") TypeError: 'NoneType'
>   object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

That happened because you're using a selenium method on a soup object.
Try it like this:

```
pagelist = driver.execute_script("""
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')].map(a => a.href)
""")
```